# Regression with SAS

Tags: sas, regression

Please see code below:

```
%macro do_regression(dep);

proc logistic data = mydata;

      class payinc0;

      model &dep= payinc0; 

      output out= &dep predicted= pd_&dep;

run;quit; %mend;

%do_regression (paydec1)

%do_regression (payinc1)

%do_regression (joblost1)

%do_regression (jobstart1)
```

I have four outcomes that I am interested in modeling. For each of these I want  to control for there levels at Time 0 in individual models. How can I modify the code for this?

Comment: Are you asking how to code a macro? If so then show the working SAS code you want the macro to generate.  Are you asking how to use PROC LOGISTIC? What did you find in the manuals?  Or are you asking how to detect "Time 0" in your dataset?  If the later then you need to describe your dataset.

Comment: I think you just need to add TIME0 to your MODEL statement. But a macro is also the old way of doing this. https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/02/13/run-1000-regressions.html

Comment: @Tom Thank you. time0 is not a variable. I have each of the exposures at time 0 e.g. as shown in the model payiunc0 that I want to control for with outcome as payinc1 (at time 1). How can I modify the macro such that it uses the respective covariate for each of the four listed outcomes?